# Run g_timeout_add in Thread Context and Not in Default Context

Tags: c, glib

I am developing a Service Application(rpm daemon). This Service provides some utilities (file transfer(FT) etc).

Now scenario is, When service gets initiated I create a saperate g_thread for FT utility. In FT utility code I have added g_timeout_add() for some purpose.

Now, I want to run source function given in (g_timeout_add) in FT thread only. Currently it is Running in default(main) context which I don't want.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5):

the `g_timeout_add()` function is a convenience for creating a `GTimeoutSource`, attaching a callback function to it, and attaching the source to the default `GMainContext`. if you need to use another `GMainContext` then you need to do what `g_timeout_add()` does, i.e.:

```
GSource *source = g_timeout_source_new (interval_in_msecs);

g_source_set_priority (source, your_priority);
g_source_set_callback (source, your_callback, your_data, your_data_notify);
g_source_set_name (source, source_name); // useful for debugging

return g_source_attach (source, your_main_context);
```

you can isolate this inside your own convenience function.

Comment: Thanks ebassi. Some code was previously written and I didn't want to change it except creating a wrapper function if I can. But finally I tried the solution from https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2013-October/msg01051.html But still I am debugging it.